# Change the dates of my visa

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I was hoping to attend a training in Germany and got a Business visa from the embassy. The training was rescheduled and my visa was only for a week. Do I have to apply at the embassy again from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

- You visa has a **duration of stay** and a **validity period**. Usually the validity period has a few more days to let you re-schedule things slightly. Have you checked if the new dates are within the old validity?
- If your biometrics have been recorded, you might not have to appear again in person.

Other than that, you need a new visa.